# how to extract difference between timestamps

Tags: postgresql, query, pgadmin, syntax

SQL greenhorn alarm:
I have a table with timestamp information (44 rows) and I now would like to calculate and extract the delta between any two consecutive rows. How can I do this? I select my data with a query like:

```
SELECT * from "table" where "RecognitionTimestamp" >= '2018-10-03 00:00:00' and "RecognitionTimestamp" <= '2018-10-04 9:00:00'
```

I'm using pgAdmin4 to submit the query and look at the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Windows Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) which provides calculation across a set of table rows that are somehow related to the current row. The list of functions are in [General-Purpose Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) section of the documentation and The lead() and lag() functions are answer of your question. Your query will should like this;

```
SELECT *,
  "RecognitionTimestamp" - lag("RecognitionTimestamp") OVER(ORDER BY "RecognitionTimestamp") AS delta_previous,
  lead("RecognitionTimestamp") OVER(ORDER BY "RecognitionTimestamp") - "RecognitionTimestamp" AS delta_next
FROM "table" 
WHERE
  "RecognitionTimestamp" >= '2018-10-03 00:00:00' AND 
  "RecognitionTimestamp" <= '2018-10-04 9:00:00'
```